# Select where timestampdiff is more than 1 day and there is some null

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns `id_user`, `to_sent` and `sent_datetime` that can be a valid `DATETIME` or `NULL`. It basically stores if something has been sent or not.

I can only send 5 for each 24 hours so in that query I need to know which `id_user` has something **to_sent=1** and has not sent anything in the last 24 hours. That to_sent=1 will also, probably, have a **sent_datetime=NULL** but I don't know how to handle it.

The sending will be later, with only distinct id_user will be OK.

I've tried

```
SELECT id_user
FROM send
WHERE
    to_sent=1
    AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, sent_datetime, NOW()) < 1)
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY updated_datetime;
```

But I don't get only the ones that have more than 24 hours from last sending something.

Comment: try adding DISTINCT before id_user and removing GROUP BY. Also add updated_datetime to SELECT (or try with SELECT * first)

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 things to check:

1. Make sure you handle the case where `sent_datetime` is null, because otherwise `TIMESTAMPDIFF` will return `NULL`. I'm not sure this is a problem here.
2. Make sure the value returned by `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is not negative. If so, invert `NOW()` and `sent_datetime` in the expression.
3. Try adding this expression in your select statement, so that you can see the result.

So, you can try this:

```
SELECT id_user, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, sent_datetime, NOW())
FROM send
WHERE
    to_sent=1
    AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, sent_datetime, NOW()) < 1)
    AND sent_datetime IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY updated_datetime;
```

Finally, you need this:

```
SELECT id_user
FROM send
WHERE
    to_sent=1
    AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, sent_datetime, NOW()) >= 1
         OR sent_datetime IS NULL)
GROUP BY id_user
ORDER BY updated_datetime;
```

Plus, this makes the accuracy in the difference to one day. You might want to change it to: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, sent_datetime, NOW()) >= 24` or minutes, or whatever. That's if you want exactly 24 hours and not a day in the calendar.

Comment: Hello! This gives me two results with difference 0. The problem is that this IDs has sent in the last 24h. I don't need that, I need from more than 24h. Thank you in advance! If I change < to > i get 0 results because sent_datetime probably could be NULL.

Comment: Then use instead of `<1` use `>1`

Comment: If I only use WHERE to_sent=1, I have 3 IDs (that's is correct), two with 0 and one with NULL. That last is where I need to send.

Comment: Use `>=` and add `AND sent_datetime IS NULL`. I'll update my answer

Comment: I get 0 rows with `>=` and `sent_datetime IS NULL` :(

Comment: With `AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, sent_datetime, NOW()) > 1)` I get 0 rows, with `AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, sent_datetime, NOW()) > 1)` I get 0 rows. The problem is that can check timestampdiff if is null?

Comment: Put it in plain english: you want to send an email to those you want to send an email to (`to_sent=1`) to whom you did not send an email to in the last day (`TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, sent_datetime, NOW()) >= 1`) or (`OR`) you never sent to (`sent_datetime IS NULL`)

Comment: Not exactly. `AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, sent_datetime, NOW()) >= 1` retuns me 0 rows when I've one row with sent_datetime that is NULL and no other entries for that id_user, so it needs to fit. Users can send a maximum of 5 every 24 hours, when they add the emails to send they are marked as sent_datetime=NULL and can have multiple entries ones with =NULL and others with a valid DATETIME.

Comment: okay, i misunderstood, what is to_sent exactly then? you need to get the number of entries that are newer than 1 day? I didn't understand...